# Replace Default image after capturing from camera in NetworkImageView

Tags: android, xml

I am facing one problem while uploading photo to server from my android Application.I want to display one default image if the image doesn't exist and if the image exists displaying the same image in image view.When am capturing image and replacing image if there is image exists, it works fine.But when there is default image and if I upload the image it will store in the server but its not getting replaced.It will replace only if I start the app by login in.Can anyone help me to resolve.I am using NetworkImageView to view the image.I am having this problem only if there is default image.
This is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is my java file to upload the image:

```
 String url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
        imageLoader = MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(StudentDetails.this).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(url, imageLoader.getImageListener(resultIv,R.drawable.new_back, R.drawable.new_back));
        resultIv.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Comment: Anyone knows where am making mistake?

Comment: maybe its because of this `imageLoader.getImageListener(resultIv,R.drawable.new_back, R.drawable.new_back))` check the last two arguments they are the same

Comment: But this code works for the existing image without any problem

Comment: i have no great knowledge on the library that is why i said maybe, but i am guessing, one of the last two arguments stands for default value that is if the image is still loading or its null, it will use it, so maybe check it and see

Comment: Do you have any idea about what I can replace there?I